# How to position elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UiMC.png)
But my code is coming out to be completely different and I am not able to figure out why.
The image is enlarged and going out of the div. Also if I try to shift the image towards right it instead is going to the left. I think I messed up in the positioning part of the image. How can I fix this issue and why is it happening? Here is my code:

```css
#title {
  background-color: #916BBF;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15%;
}

/* Download Buttons */
.download-button {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}

/* Title */
.title-img {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
}

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.feature-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <!-- CSS bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JS bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Title -->
  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-img" src="https://www.transparentpng.com/thumb/-iphone-x/jPIkq8-iphone-glass-lens-screen-replacement-fixez.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Take a look to flexbox

Comment: Can you replace image class with "img-fluid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and took your width off your `img class` and added a few styles. Next steps to achieve this look would be to contain your h1 and buttons on the left and provide a margin left.

**EDIT:**

I also added a `col-sm-6` Bootstrap class to your `col-lg-6` to make it mobile responsive. The `@media only screen` on your img class allows you to adjust the img to make it positioned just right on a different device.

```css
#title {
  background-color: #916BBF;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15%;
}

/* Download Buttons */
.download-button {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}
/* Title */
 .title-img {
   transform: rotate(27deg);
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 5rem;
   overflow-x: hidden;
  }

/* Title Responsive */
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.title-img {
    transform: rotate(27deg);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    right: 2rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
}

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.feature-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <!-- CSS bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JS bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Title -->
  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
          <img class="title-img" src="https://www.transparentpng.com/thumb/-iphone-x/jPIkq8-iphone-glass-lens-screen-replacement-fixez.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But this isn't responsive to smaller screens. It hides the image

Comment: Please see the adjusted answer. I added a 'col-sm-6' to your col-lg-6 to fit a media screen. It wasn't stated in the question that you were wanted it mobile responsive, you just stated your image wasn't coming out as you anticipated. Please be sure to include that next time.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <!-- CSS bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JS bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<style>
#title {
  background-color: #916BBF;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15%;
}

/* Download Buttons */
.download-button {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}

/* Title */
.title-img {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: relative;
}

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -128px;
}

.feature-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

</style>
<body>
  <!-- Title -->
  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-img" src="https://www.transparentpng.com/thumb/-iphone-x/jPIkq8-iphone-glass-lens-screen-replacement-fixez.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-md-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-md-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-md-4">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).